# GSConnect drops connection and WhatsApp not working

Tags: android, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, 19.04, whatsapp

I am experimenting with GSConnect for the first time.  I have followed the [instructions here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/11/connect-android-ubuntu-gsconnect) and have managed to:

- Connect to the phone and exchange files (in both directions),
- Send and receive SMS messages, and
- Ping my desktop from my phone and vice versa.

Some details about my setup:

- Mobile phone: LG G5, Android 7.0.
- Ubuntu desktop: upgraded earlier today from 18.10 to 19.04.
- Installed the [GSConnect GNOME Shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/) through Ubuntu Software.
- Installed plugin on Firefox (just updated to 66.0.3).

Although there is some delay with the messages (especially when a message is received), this seems to work properly.

Unfortunately, I have identified the following two issues:

1. The connection drops every few minutes and I need to reconnect.  This often takes more than one attempt and I can only reconnect if I initiate this from the phone (pinging, for instance, does the trick).
2. I am unable to connect with WhatApp even though the [instructions I am following](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/11/connect-android-ubuntu-gsconnect) seem to explicitly say this is possible.

If anyone has experience with GSConnect and can help, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

unluckily I only have 1 point and I can not comment your post.

please generate the [support log as explained in their wiki](https://github.com/andyholmes/gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect/wiki/Help#generate-support-log) and share with us the result. We will help you troubleshoot the issues.

The possible reasons could be

1) [Intereference with other Equipment](https://github.com/andyholmes/gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect/wiki/Help#interference-with-other-equipment)

> Some users have reported that KDE Connect broadcasts (UDP Port 1716) can interfere with some equipment. The cause is unknown, but seems to only affect very very network connected devices such as PLCs and WiFi repeaters.

Could be possible that activating other equipment is the cause of your connection instability.

2) Issues related to the distribution package.

Ubuntu 19.04 is incompatible with many `apt` packages which have not yet been troubleshootet, we would need information on how did you install `gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect` and all the relevant software.

I remain available for additional information.

The [wiki](https://github.com/andyholmes/gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect) has several information about the extension, please include any other relevant link to packages and software.